# Is there a way to optimize the generation of Abelian Sandpile Zeros?

Tags: python, loops, optimization

I wrote this Python code to generate zero elements, of arbitrary size, from abelian sandpile groups:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

NaN = np.nan

def trough(N):
    (i,j) = np.shape(N)
    Nt = np.concatenate((np.ones((i,1))*NaN, N, np.ones((i,1))*NaN), axis=1)
    Nt = np.concatenate((np.ones((1,j+2))*NaN, Nt, np.ones((1,j+2))*NaN), axis=0)
    return Nt
"""
test = np.ones((3,3))
print(trough(test))
"""

def topple(N):
    P = trough(N)
    sP = np.shape(P)
    while np.nanmax(P) > 3:
        for (i,j) in np.ndindex(sP):
            if P[i,j] > 3 and np.isnan(P[i,j]) == False:
                P[i,j] -= 4
                P[i+1,j] += 1
                P[i-1,j] += 1
                P[i,j+1] += 1
                P[i,j-1] += 1
    return P[1:-1,1:-1]

def Picard(m,n):
    P1 = 6*np.ones((m,n))
    P1 = topple(P1)
    P2 = 6*np.ones((m,n))
    Pi = P2 - P1
    Pi = topple(Pi)
    return Pi

M = 500
N = 500
Pi = Picard(M,N)

cmap = cm.get_cmap('viridis_r')

plt.figure()
plt.axes(aspect='equal')
plt.axis('off')
plt.pcolormesh(Pi, cmap=cmap)

dim = str(N) + 'x' + str(M)
file_name = 'Picard_Identity-' + dim + '.png'

plt.savefig(file_name)
```

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_sandpile_model) is a Wikipedia page explaining what the abelian sandpile model is.

The code works, but is very slow, especially for large arrays. It does feature an if loop within a  while loop. What are some methods I could use to optimize this program?

Comment: Consider moving this to Code Review, since it works.

Comment: look at `numba` package

Answer (score 0):

A method to considerably reduce the running time is to do with less explicit loops. We can do so by means of boolean array indexing, with shifted sections for the neighbors:

```
def topple(N):
    P = trough(N)
    while True:
        ind = P[1:-1,1:-1] > 3
        if not ind.any(): break
        P[1:-1,1:-1][ind] -= 4
        P[ :-2,1:-1][ind] += 1  # above
        P[1:-1,2:  ][ind] += 1  # right
        P[2:  ,1:-1][ind] += 1  # below
        P[1:-1, :-2][ind] += 1  # left
    return P[1:-1,1:-1]
```